# vba macro powerpoint with selected shapes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a simple macro that made shapes appear and disapear as you click on them, in loop.

To use the macro I have to paste my shapes in an empty slide.

I would like to improve the macro and could use it in a slide with other shapes, select the shapes and apply the macro to them but not to the rest of unselected shapes.

Any idea? Thanks

Here is the code

```
Sub Createanimation()

Set oSld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

Z = oSld.Shapes.Count

For i = 1 To Z

Set oEffect1 = oSld.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Add.AddEffect(Shape:=oSld.Shapes(i), effectId:=msoAnimEffectAppear, Trigger:=msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick)
    If i = 1 Then
    oEffect1.Timing.TriggerShape = oSld.Shapes(Z)
    Else
    oEffect1.Timing.TriggerShape = oSld.Shapes(i - 1)
    End If
    oEffect1.Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious



Set oEffect2 = oSld.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Add.AddEffect(Shape:=oSld.Shapes(i), effectId:=msoAnimEffectAppear, Trigger:=msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick)
    oEffect2.Exit = msoCTrue
    oEffect2.Timing.TriggerShape = oSld.Shapes(i)
    oEffect2.Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious

Next i

oSld.Shapes.Range.Align msoAlignMiddles, msoTrue
oSld.Shapes.Range.Align msoAlignCenters, msoTrue


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to get all the selected shapes in active slide:

```
Dim Shp As Shape
For Each Shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
'Put code for action on each shape here

Next
```

If you want to use counter:

```
Dim Shp As Shape, SelectedShapes as Shapes

Set SelectedShapes = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
For i=1 to SelectedShapes.Count
Set Shp = SelectedShapes(i)
'Put code for action on each shape here

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, based on your counter mode I could made the macro work as I wanted

```
Sub Createanimation()

Set oSld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide


Dim Shp As Shape, SelectedShapes As Shapes

Z = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count


For i = 1 To Z

Set oEffect1 = oSld.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Add.AddEffect(Shape:=ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(i), effectId:=msoAnimEffectAppear, Trigger:=msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick)
    If i = 1 Then
    oEffect1.Timing.TriggerShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(Z)
    Else
    oEffect1.Timing.TriggerShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(i - 1)
    End If
    oEffect1.Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious



Set oEffect2 = oSld.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Add.AddEffect(Shape:=ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(i), effectId:=msoAnimEffectAppear, Trigger:=msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick)
    oEffect2.Exit = msoCTrue
    oEffect2.Timing.TriggerShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(i)
    oEffect2.Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious

Next i

ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, msoTrue
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, msoTrue


End Sub
```